# Font Scaling on iPhone 6 plus looks like rasterized scaling in Revolution Slider

Tags: css, iphone, font-size, revolution-slider

I am working on a site, [vimaxmedia.com](http://vimaxmedia.com) and we are using revolution slider. The slider is configured to be Full Width Responsive.

The problem I am having is, on the iPhone 6+ for some reason, the font looks like it is not scaling as a vector font, but a rasterized font. I have tried replicating the issue on my desktop, but I am unable to and I am unsure how to even start debugging this. I do have access to a 6+ to test.

Has anyone else had this issue, and does anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It appears that the way revolution slider is calculating the matrix3d transform was causing the issue.

I added the following css entry

```
.tp-caption { -webkit-transform: none !important; }
```

I only use that for my "xsmall" responsive stylesheet.